# How to sum occurrence elements count in java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I want to find occurrence elements sum in java 8 and using my below technique i am getting all elements sum but i want to find only itemType=EQUIPMENT elements sum

Can some one help me please

```
double sum = itemList.stream().mapToDouble(a -> a.getQuantity())
                    .sum();

[
        {
            "itemType": "EQUIPMENT",
            "quantity": 6
        },
        {
            "itemType": "DTVN",
            "quantity": 2
        },
        {
            "itemType": "EQUIPMENT",
            "quantity": 1
        }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter a particular itemType using `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` based on what you want

```
double sum = itemList.stream()
                .filter(type->"EQUIPMENT".equals(type.getItemType()))
                .mapToDouble(a -> a.getQuantity())
                .sum();
```

Comment: How can we check a.getQuantity() null check?